# Will people buy a book about my life when it involves years of abuse?

Tags: autobiography

I have been writing about my life of pain and suffering for a while and now I am taking it to the next level.

On the outside, we were like the perfect family, but the reality was far from normal. My husband was a property tycoon who lied, had affairs with prostitutes, and committed extortion. We had gangsters chasing us, burning our cars, making kidnapping and death threats... the list goes on and on. I eventually got away but it took many years and I am now building my life with my girls. He is worth $25 million and I helped him get there, but then he stripped me of everything and I cannot even get a penny of child support, though we are in a court battle. He is the devil.

I am not famous but very well known in my city. Will people buy a book about my life?

Comment: Hi Cindy, welcome to Writing. One of our site's rules is that questions must be *objectively answerable*, whereas your question "Will people buy a book about my life?" invites personal opinion, so I'm voting to close it. Please read [ask] and take our site's [Tour] to get a better understanding of what we're looking for in a question. FWIW, people will buy your book if it's well written, engaging, and well marketed. If it's self-published, this will reduce your potential market, and if it's not professionally edited, it may not be as readable, further limiting potential sales. :-)

Comment: You are testing an **elevator pitch** rather than asking an actual writing question. Asking for critiques are *off topic* because they don't help anyone else.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I have hired a ghost writer as I have no clue how to write but thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking if there's an audience for your autobiography, right?
I'd say you have two audiences to shoot for:

A. Those that know your name, and unless it's known in several cities, I'd expect that to be the smaller but more reliable pool.
B. Those that can relate, identify, or sympathize with your story regardless of your name. I'd expect this to be the larger but more transient pool.

Personally, I'd suggest using A to get you to B.

Again, you're asking if people want to know your story. They will read it either because it's yours, or because they appreciate the story. Write the story well, and get both audiences.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My husband was a Traditional all Muslim well half the week anyway and he expected me to convert. I didn’t convert and for that I was treated very bad. My 5 daughters have suffered but I got them therapy and they are all ok. They are a credit to me. They are the most humble well mannered balanced young girls I’ve ever known. They survived. I have been trying to find a book with a similar story but couldn’t find anything. I have decided to hire a ghost writer to tell my story. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer was excellent. There are autobiographies being written all the time, by celebrities, by successful business people, etc. It shows just how much a person has gone through to get to where they are today, and a lot of people talk about abuse as well. There will be people who relate to your story, especially since so many people also go through similar types of abuse.

Comment: Thank you. I am doing very well have my own business and joined an African gospel choir years ago as singing was my dream and I wasn’t allowed as I was a Muslim wife but my self and my 5 daughters are all doing great considering 